# Sonata forms in own Bundle

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-sonata

i try use collection form type (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) on my standard form but this need to i create for each form my custom template and put javascript to add -remove entities. (i need many crud entities forms)

So maybe is possible to use sonata form generator - in my custom Bundles - i see this have ready to use form menager - witch nice look - css, js.

Where i can find how to use sonata form generator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently in the process of refactoring the form types in a new - more generic - Sonata bundle, see https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle.

You might want to follow up on this repository for your dependencies.

However you are already able to use those custom form types, simply by calling them in your front end as you would in the back end. (For instance by setting the type to 'sonata_model_list').

Be sure that required CSS and JS are included in your templates (same as needed by the admin bundle currently).